# attempted relative import with no known parent package **

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting  attempted relative import with no known parent package in my python file . but when I set ".sql" or "sql" in import  it doesn't differ . the image of files :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUwYU.jpg)

Comment: You need more information and please don't include images of code, always the code itself (along with the project structure since we're talking about imports). As for the problem, I think if the .py file you are running is `manage.py` then the import would have to be `from TechnoAlert.sql import`

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use such names as file names. `sql` is an awful name for a file as there can be hundreds of packages which use a similar file.
2. Why are you working in TechnoAlert? That is not how you use Django. [Please check the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/).
   That is your entire server's settings folder, you are supposed to create an app.